# Add class to single element and not all using JQuery on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a class to an icon when I hover over an anchor tag on my page.

However **when I hover it applies the hover class to ALL the elements** with the icon class. How can I single this so it only targets the icon in the column I am hovering within.

Thanks in advance.

```js
$('.column-content-link a').hover(function(){
   $('.column-content .icon').toggleClass('hover');
   $('.column-content h3').toggleClass('hover');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column-content">
        <div class="column-content-header">
                <i class="icon fa fa-rocket"></i>
            <h3 class="">Heading 1</h3>
            <p><span>Blue bottle heirloom cronut, iceland salvia austin swag af photo booth church-key vinyl yuccie pour-over venmo bitters. Drinking vinegar humblebrag banh mi godard. Cronut lyft actually iceland, pabst chia small batch fam. Aesthetic organic ennui stumptown. </span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="column-content-link">
                <a href="https://www.google.com">Learn more</a>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="column-content">
        <div class="column-content-header">
                <i class="icon fa fa-rocket"></i>
            <h3 class="">Heading 2</h3>
            <p><span>Blue bottle heirloom cronut, iceland salvia austin swag af photo booth church-key vinyl yuccie pour-over venmo bitters. Drinking vinegar humblebrag banh mi godard. Cronut lyft actually iceland, pabst chia small batch fam. Aesthetic organic ennui stumptown. </span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="column-content-link">
                <a href="https://www.google.com">Learn more</a>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="column-content">
        <div class="column-content-header">
                <i class="icon fa fa-rocket"></i>
            <h3 class="">Heading 3</h3>
            <p><span>Blue bottle heirloom cronut, iceland salvia austin swag af photo booth church-key vinyl yuccie pour-over venmo bitters. Drinking vinegar humblebrag banh mi godard. Cronut lyft actually iceland, pabst chia small batch fam. Aesthetic organic ennui stumptown. </span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="column-content-link">
                <a href="https://www.google.com">Learn more</a>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="column-content">
        <div class="column-content-header">
                <i class="icon fa fa-rocket"></i>
            <h3 class="">Heading 4</h3>
            <p><span>Blue bottle heirloom cronut, iceland salvia austin swag af photo booth church-key vinyl yuccie pour-over venmo bitters. Drinking vinegar humblebrag banh mi godard. Cronut lyft actually iceland, pabst chia small batch fam. Aesthetic organic ennui stumptown. </span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="column-content-link">
                <a href="https://www.google.com">Learn more</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Traverse to closest parent element(`.column-content`) and then find target elements in it:

```
$('.column-content-link a').hover(function(){
  var $closestColContent = $(this).closest('.column-content');
  closestColContent.find('.icon,h3').toggleClass('hover');
});
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you for your input. Is there any disadvantage to doing it this way:  `$('.column-content-link a').hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.icon').toggleClass('hover');    
    $(this).parent().parent().find('h3').toggleClass('hover');    
    });`

Comment: Yes there is.Above code will break if you add or remove one of the parent. Its always better to choose selector precisely using id or class. That way the chances of breaking the code when dom changes are minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this)` context instead of `$('.column-content .icon')`